# Unable to install podfile to my Xcode project

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.1.1

When I try to $ pod install , I keep on getting this error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
  pod ...rebase/Database'

/Users/QusaiHussain/scheduler_1/Podfile:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
  pod 'Goo...se/Auth'base'

/Users/QusaiHussain/scheduler_1/Podfile:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
  pod 'Google'base/Auth'

 #  from /Users/QusaiHussain/scheduler_1/Podfile:8

 #  -------------------------------------------

 #  
  pod 'Google'e/Auth'ase'
 #      
 #  -------------------------------------------

[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: could you show us how the pod file looks like?

Comment: Had to adjust the quotations. Go it fixed thanks!